# generate object based on parameters count

Tags: c++

I would like to refactor my code. I have 3 classes that differ only by the number of points they take to be initialized (from 2 to 4). They all have the same method name and number, but their implementation is (really) different.

I would like to have a class that, depending on the number of points, constructs the appropriate object. I would also like to be able to declare function prototypes (using this class) for all bézier curves, eg:

`void function(const bezier& curve);`

The header file:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "glm/vec2.hpp"

struct Custom // tmp struc will be removed
{
    float distance;
    glm::vec2 point;
};

//need to find a way to have only one class for all of bezier

class Bezier3
{
public:
    glm::vec2 m_P_0, m_P_1, m_P_2, m_P_3;
    // count is for debugging purposes will be removed
    size_t m_Count = 100;

    Bezier3(const glm::vec2& p_0, const glm::vec2& p_1, const glm::vec2& p_2, const glm::vec2& p_3, const size_t& m_Count);
    ~Bezier3();

    glm::vec2 operator() (const float& t);
    glm::vec2 derivate(const float& t);
    Custom findClosestPoint(const glm::vec2& point, double& start);

};

class Bezier2
{
public:
    glm::vec2 m_P_0, m_P_1, m_P_2;
    size_t m_Count = 100;

    Bezier2(const glm::vec2& p_0, const glm::vec2& p_1, const glm::vec2& p_2, const size_t& m_Count);
    ~Bezier2();

    glm::vec2 operator() (const float& t);
    glm::vec2 derivate(const float& t);
    Custom findClosestPoint(const glm::vec2& point);

};


class Bezier1
{
public:
    glm::vec2 m_P_0, m_P_1;
    size_t m_Count = 100;

    Bezier1(const glm::vec2& p_0, const glm::vec2& p_1, const size_t& m_Count);
    ~Bezier1();

    glm::vec2 operator() (const float& t);
    glm::vec2 derivate(const float& t);
    Custom findClosestPoint(const glm::vec2& point);
};
```

Is this possible? I did some research, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Seems to me that you just need 1 class with a `std::vector<glm::vec2>` that you can add points to at runtime as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
class Bezier
{
public:
  Bezier(const glm::vec2& p_0, const glm::vec2& p_1, const size_t& m_Count) : impl(Bezier1(p_0, p_1, m_Count)) {}
  Bezier(const glm::vec2& p_0, const glm::vec2& p_1, const glm::vec2& p_2, const size_t& m_Count) : impl(Bezier2(p_0, p_1, p_2, m_Count)) {}
  Bezier(const glm::vec2& p_0, const glm::vec2& p_1, const glm::vec2& p_2, const glm::vec2& p_3, const size_t& m_Count) : impl(Bezier3(p_0, p_1, p_2, p_3, m_Count)) {}
  // Other functions
  // ...
private:
  std::variant<Bezier1, Bezier2, Bezier3> impl;
};
```

If you want to decide on type dynamically, e.g. if you have vector of `glm::vec2` you can do that too.